# How to add a number in above rows?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I m solving this pattern in c++:

- 1
- 2 7
- 3 6 8
- 4 5 9 10

I have 2 logic to solve this pattern but I m stuck:

**1 logic using a loop**:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool flag=true;
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
         if(i<=4) //when 4 column then if print the 5 //it is execute perfactly
         {   
           flag=false;
           cout<<endl;
           cout<<i;

           for(int column=4;column<=i;column++)
           {
               flag=true;
               column=column+1;       
               cout<<column;
           }
         }

         //here now i want to add a 6 in 3 column but not proper output
//       if(i<=3)
//       {   
//         flag=false;
//         cout<<endl;
//         cout<<i;

//         for(int column=3;column<=i;column++)
//         {
//             flag=true;
//             column=column+1;       
//             cout<<column;
//         }
//       }
    }
}
```

current output:

[image]

**2 logic store the element in the array**:

What I m trying:

4 row and different column size each row

int elementstore[4][] = { 1, 2, 7, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5, 9, 10};

- the first row means 1 store in 1 row
- the second row means 2,7 store in 2 row
- the third row means 3,6,8 store in 3 row
- the fourth row means 4,5,9,10 store in 4 column

```
[0][0]=1

[1][0]=2
[1][1]=7

[2][0]=3
[2][1]=6
[2][2]=8

[3][0]=4
[3][1]=5
[3][2]=9
[3][3]=10
```

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int *column_array[4];
     int mapping_array[4] = {1,2,3,4};  //4 column
     int i;//row
     int j;//column

     for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
       column_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*column_array[i]); //here i m facing the error
     }
}
```

error is:
error: invalid operands of types ‘long unsigned int’ and ‘int*’ to binary ‘operator*’

I hope I apply logic on the above program right way?

which way to solve this pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would start from an array that looks like below:

```
1 2 3 4
7 6 5
8 9
10
```

You can populate the array by default values or by using loops:

```c
int ar[4][4];

void generate ()
{
  int num = 1;
  bool flag = true;
  for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        if (flag) 
        {
            for (int colm = 0; colm < 4 - row; colm++)
            {
                ar[row][colm] = num;
                num++;
            }

            flag = !flag;
        } 
        else 
        {
            for (int colm = 4 - (row + 1); colm >= 0; colm--)
            {
                ar[row][colm] = num;
                num++;
            }

            flag = !flag;
        }
    }

}
```

Now as you have the array, you can print them the order you want:

```c
void printInOrder(){
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        for (int colm = 0, mv = 0; colm <= row; colm++, mv++)
        {
            cout << ar[colm][row-mv] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
7 6 5
8 9
10

1
2 7
3 6 8
4 5 9 10
```

- [Code Link](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk8ZiUzEL)

Comment: when I m trying your program facing the issue see this link: https://onlinegdb.com/rkXSFBf4L can u help more? I can not debug your programme

Comment: thanks can u tell me what is ```mv=0```  which type of variable? I don't see not declare anywhere

Comment: `mv` is an `int` type of variable, declared inside the loop definition, `for( int ...)`

Comment: thanks give your valuable time and effort to solve this logic

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve it mathematically, find which number will be at position `(i, j)`, where `i` - the row number, `j` - the column number.

Then the pyramid will look like

```
(0, 0)
(1, 0) (1, 1)
(2, 0) (2, 1) (2, 2)
```

Hint: Assume you need to output `r` rows, then the first column will have `r` elements, second column will have `r - 1` elements, and so on.

Comment: can u explain more detail plz ```(3-0) = 3 , (3-1) = 2 , (3-2) = 1 , (3-3) = 0``` I m not properly understood

Comment: Where did you get these numbers from? It's not (3 - 0), it is (3, 0) - the coordinates. And the value in this coordinate will depend on how many rows do you have.

Comment: ok as per your logic 2nd row ```(4-2) = 2 column``` and ```3rd row (4-3) = 1 column```  and ```4rd row (4-4) = 0 column``` is the wrong or right?

Comment: What is the column of `(1, 1)`?

Comment: now I  m understood ```(1,1) = 1,(2,1) = 2 and (2,2) =7,(3,1) = 3 and (3,2)=6 and (3,3)=8,(4,1) = 4 and (4,2)=5 and (4,3)=9 and (4,4)=10```